# ternary operator in camel simple expression

Tags: apache-camel, talend

Using the ternary operator logic as described here
http://www.davsclaus.com/2011/09/camel-29-much-improved-simple-language.html

I am trying to set a exchange property called StatusMsg2 like so, where
exchangeProperty.StatusMsg = 'abc'

```
.setProperty("StatusMsg2")
.simple("${exchangeProperty.StatusMsg} == null ? 'ee2e2e2' : 'fffffff'")
```

That sets StatusMsg2 to the the string

```
abc == null ? 'ee2e2e2' : 'fffffff'
```

as the value, rather than evaluating the expression.

I am using camel 2.29, albeit in Talend Studio. But Talend renders plain ol' camel as I've outputted.

And I have checked my spaces are correct

if I replace with

```
.simple("true ? 'ee2e2e2' : 'fffffff'")
```

I get the string

```
true ? 'ee2e2e2' : 'fffffff'
```

If I do

```
simple(true ? "ee2e2e2" : "fffffff")
```

I then get the string

```
ee2e2e2
```

If I try

```
.simple("${exchangeProperty.StatusMsg} == null" ? "ee2e2e2" : "fffffff")
```

I get a "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean" compilation error

How do I get the first part of my ternary expression to be recognised
as an expression itself?

Thanks for any advice

n

Comment: Ternary operator is not supported in Simple language and you already got the same answer on mailing list yesterday from Claus - author of blog you are referencing, technical lead of Camel project, who is working on Camel since the first commit 10 years ago. Do you expect more reputable source, or why are you asking again here?

Comment: Sorry - I've not seen that response from Claus....it's not in my spam either...i can't see it in nabble either....http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/struggling-with-ternary-operator-on-simple-expression-td5889901.html. please can you add it here?

Comment: I got the response on mailing list. You are right, on nabble it is somehow incorrectly paired with original email, the Claus's response is here http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Re-struggling-with-ternary-operator-on-simple-expression-tt5889904.html

Comment: Just a bit more detail. The blogpost you are referring mentions ternary operators as "Experiment" and in ended up a experiment only. It was never implemented into Camel codebase.

Comment: Btw working on compiled simple language (experiment now) but at first working on a new camel-joor language that uses java code, so you can then use javas ternary operator: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/joor-language.html

Comment: Love the Camel Project! Such a Swiss army toolkit. Groovy worked very well by the way :)